# Multi-level survival modeling

Tags: survival, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I'm struggling with choosing the appropriate model for a study I'm doing where I determine the survival times of certain technological applications. The goal here is to estimate how long individuals use certain technologies, and whether certain covariates have an impact on said survival time.

A couple of characteristics of the data:

- Since my most important independent variable tends to vary over time, the data is time-dependent. So one row = 1 specific day for one specific technology for one specific individual.
- Some technologies are used by multiple individuals. So some technologies have multiple survival times.
- Some of the technologies are right-censored (i.e. the individual still uses the technology after we've finished the data collection).

So, the data structure looks something like this:
[image: Data structure]

I'm struggling with choosing the most appropriate modeling strategy here.

- **I'm pretty sure** I want to take the variance explained by the ID-level into account.
- **I'm not sure** whether I want to treat the technologies as a separate level. *Some* technologies are shared among multiple individuals, but not all of them. And if they're shared, most technologies are only shared by a handful of individuals. I have the impression that it's useless to take the technology-level into account due to the low sample size of most technologies in the dataset. Maybe it makes more sense to recode every technology as being unique, so the technology-factor only appears within one ID.

I think a **cox proportional hazards model** with time-dependent covariates makes sense here. With the the survival package in R, it's really straightforward to add time-dependent covariates (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf). However, I'm stuck with defining the ID-cluster here. In their paper, the authors claim :

> One common question with this data setup is whether we need to worry about correlated data, since a given subject has multiple observations. The answer is no, we do not. The reason is that this representation is simply a programming trick. The likelihood equations at any time point use only one copy of any subject, the program picks out the correct row of data at each time. There two exceptions to this rule: When subjects have multiple events, then the rows for the events are correlated within subject and a cluster variance is needed.

The problem here is that ID's *do* experience multiple events, but the time variable restarts at 1 whenever a new technology is used, since all events are clustered within a specific technology. This situation doesn't match the data formatting used by the examples in this paper (or some other papers I've found, for that matter).

Can someone help me out on the appropriate model strategy here? More specifically, I'd like to know whether

(a) it makes sense to take the ID-level into account, but not the technology-level (due to low sample size on this lower level) and

(b) what kind of survival model I should use here. I've also looked at **nested frailty models**, but I'm not sure whether this is the right way to go.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If a person can continue to use technology A and B, then your endpoints are not mutually exclusive. Thus, you need separate models for each technology if you are interested in time until cessation of use pertinent to each technology. Within models for each technology, consider a time-dependent covariate for concurrent use of other technologies or simpler, non-time-dependent variables for past use.

As for modeling by individual, if the interest is how rapidly a person cycles, consider using adoption of a new technology as a failure time and then model multiple adoption/switching events using a model allowing for repeated events. I do not see a way to account for repeated failure times if measures for each technology must be made.